# Diet for cat with higher liver enzymes

Tags: cats, health, diet, liver-disease

My cat is almost two years old, Persian and weight around 3.3 kg.

After adopting her 6 months ago I noticed that she poops outside the litter box unintentionally (once I caught her trying to remove it/ cover it), and lately she wasn’t eating enough and started to throw her food everywhere (she is sterilized). Anyways, her vet told us after having blood test and X-rays that she have increased level of liver enzymes (should be 100-130 max and her results were 200). Also, he said that the x-rays shows a lot of gas and that these two factors might be the cause of her case (pooping outside the little box).

Her vet suggested giving her 2 shots every 2 weeks for 2 months to help with her situation along with hepatic (for liver) dry food (any brand). The problem is that all hepatic food contains large amounts of grains (usually first ingredient), and there isn’t a lot of options at all! I found only 4 brands offering hepatic dry food (Royal Canin, Hills, Happy Cat, Purina).

I know her vet recommended these, but is it actually healthy? Is there any other alternative that I’m not aware of? If I want to use regular cat food what shall I look for?

Note: I already tried Happy Cat Vet Hepatic for her and the first day I noticed that poop was stuck on her fur but the issue didn’t happen again (it’s been 5 weeks). Also, she seems more energetic.. However, I couldn’t find more stock so I’m looking for alternatives.